# SELECT * from table like from text box. (vb.net 2008 + ms access 2003)

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2003

I've been trying make a SQL LIKE statement for a search button to display data to, but it doesn't work . I've tried searching about it and even copy-pasted some of the working codes but still no.. I'm really new to this so please excuse my fail coding.

(vb.net 2008 + ms access 2003)
here's my code :

```
item = txtsearch.Text
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
        con.Open()

            cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM moviedb WHERE Title Like = '%" & item & "%' ", con)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            If (dr.Read() = True) Then



                da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM moviedb WHERE Title  = '%" & item & "%' ", con)

                da.Fill(ds, "List")

                DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("List")

     con.Close()
```

I've also tried changing the "%" to "*", but yeah still doesn't do it.
It says Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Title LIKE = '%@item%''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things wrong in your code:

First, where do you set the connection string?

```
 Dim con = new OleDbConnection(.....connection string here ....)
```

The connection string is essential to open the database, without it you cannot call the Open method on the connection. This site contains a lot of connection strings examples, included the one for Access 2003 [ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/)

Second, you need to use a parameterized query to avoid problems if your text to search for contains a single quotes (and of course to avoid Sql Injections)

Third, you don't need to query two times the database just to discover if there are records returned by the query. You could directly bind the return to your grid or test the number of rows returned in the table `List` of the dataset

```
Dim ds As New DataSet

Using con = new OleDbConnection(......constring....)
Using cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM moviedb WHERE Title Like ?", con)
    con.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "%" & item & "%")
    Using da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
         da.Fill(ds, "List")
         DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("List")

    End Using
End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm sorry about the connection string, it was there but haven't included cause it was at the top. That was just a part of the whole btn code.

Comment: oops should have used the anwer button below, sorry.

Comment: Check also the answer from G_Wilson. I have not seen that. LIKE is the unique operator needed here

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same, but here is the correct way:

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM moviedb WHERE Title Like  '%" & item & "%' ", con)
```

You have to remove the `=` sign

Answer (score 0):

Also, another thing. You don't need an `=` Operator when your using `LIKE` i have found.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this :

```
"SELECT * FROM moviedb WHERE Title Like = '%" & item & "%'", con
```

[source](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/329296/sql-like-in-sql-string-vb.net)